# How to add new file extensions to resolve? (Webpack & angular-cli)

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

In webpack you can configure the different file types/extensions, which you want to resolve. In angular-cli is no webpack-config.

Is there away to add/configure this kind of configuration? I would like that my application also takes `*.tsx` files.

**Update**

I know there is the `ng eject`, but I don't want to lose the CLI functionality. Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can <strike>fork the CLI and `npm link` your fork</strike> run [`npm eject`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject), which creates a copy of the Webpack configuration, and you can customize it yourself, not through the CLI anymore.

Check the official docs: [Moving your project out of Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-moving-out-of-the-cli)
And then if you want to revert it, you can [move back in](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-moving-into-the-cli) and lose customizations.

If you want to stick to what the CLI gives, then this is not available at the moment.

Webpack is currently hidden away from the end-user of the CLI as much as possible.

A CLI-specific (likely build-tool-independent, as in: non Webpack specific) extensibility / plugin architecture is to be considered for the Angular CLI v2.0.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for the answer. Have you, by any chance, ever used a react-component in a angular2 app?

Comment: No. I wouldn't! You probably can, maybe by just enabling `tsx` option in `src/tsconfig.json`(although not sure if Webpack will pick that still), but just because you can, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Okay. I see! The problem is that I've to bring one dependency in, which is build with react. I could add the bundled version of the react-component to the index.html, but that also doesn't feel right.

Comment: Importing entire react for a single component is an overkill I believe.

Comment: Now we can do something called **eject**, which gives us full access to webpack. This should allow us to add files with different file extensions.